How to integrate Next Js app as cross domain component with Zoid?
I'm trying to use zoid with a Next Js app to load in another domain site.The other domain site is a plain JS HTML/CSS website.
Can't seem to find a working example with code for Next Js to accomplish my requirement.
My requirements:
Next js is the child app, the parent app is a plain HTML page using script tag to load zoid.
I need to open the next js app in a iframe modal on a button click from the cross domain website. I need to pass some props from parent to the child and some props back to parent from the child.
